# g_massstorage device in windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, device

I would like to use my OrangePi zero as a g_masstorage(USB gadget). Successfully make OPI as a g_massstorage device based on [enter link description here][1]
  [1]: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/bcmdhd-3.10/Documentation/usb/mass-storage.txt.OPI successfully mounted in Ubuntu also  Ubuntu PC detect the device as a storage device. But the issue is with Windows PC. The device detected and  shows to format the storage device.. How to use the g_massstorage device in Windows? How to mount USB gadget for windows PC? Used to mount the OPI as

> sudo modprobe g_mass_storage file=/dev/sda1 stall=0 removable=1 idVendor= idProduct= iManufacturer="MXTronics" iProduct="MXT USB Device" iSerialNumber=

Answer (score 0):

I think, wrong FS type. If your /dev/sda1 is ext2\ext4 or something else linux fs type, your pc with windows will try to format it. Try to use ntfs file format, any other fs format that can be recognized by windows. There are good instruction https://linux-sunxi.org/USB_Gadget/Mass_storage